# KissFFT library

Tags: fft

Does anyone know if there is a limitation in the KissFFT library with regards to the relationship between FFT size and the frame size used(number of samples as input/output)? I'm trying to implement 75% overlap add and it works only if the segment size is half of the FFT size.

Regards,
Naveen

Answer (score 1):

FFT takes in as many numbers as it churns out. What you are trying to do is in conflict with this so it's not KissFFT's fault. I've found KissFFT to work just as good as any other FFT library.

Comment: Hi Olli, I didn't quite understand the conflict that you mentioned. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: I got the impression that you think it is possible to vary the size of input to FFT of a certain size. That is not correct.